# How to change the value of variable using reactjs code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, types, boolean

How to change the value of variable using reactjs code? The variable that I want to change has a boolean data type, in which I want to change the value of the variable from false to true.

The variable that I want to change using the reactjs code looks like this.

```
const maintenance = false;
```

Comment: You can't change a `const` variable after it is assgined. Also, what does this have to do with react? Are you saving this in `state`?

Comment: No, I am not saving this in state. I just want to change the value of  "maintenance" variable from false to true with reactjs

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need an actual variable and not a constant, so:

```
let maintenance = false;
```

Then to reassign/change the value just do:

```
maintenance = true;
```

You change the value of the variable with the "=". It assigns new value.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. But, how to change the value of variable from false to true by clicking a button using reactjs?

Answer (score 0):

Using State

```
import {useState} from 'react';
function App(){
 const [maintenance,setMaintenance]=useState(false);
 handleClick(){
 setMaintenance(true);
 }
 return(
     <div> 
         <button onClick={handleClick}>change</button>
         <p> Maintenance : {maintenance} </p>
     </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. But, how to change the value of variable from false to true by clicking a button using reactjs?

Comment: check i have edited the code ,added button